# Confirming there is a range of characters in a string in order

Tags: java, string

I am a little stuck on how to work out if a string contains a range of characters in a set order. (true/false)

Eg.  abc1deeef2hh hijk3lmno

So I need to check if this string contains a 1, 2, 3 in a set order.  So 3 can't come before 2 or 1 etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take here is to remove all non numeric characters, and then simply make a single pass down the string, checking to make sure that no subsequent number is less than what came before it.

```
public static boolean isInOrder(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    String inputNums = input.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
    char prev = inputNums.charAt(0);
    for (int i=1; i < inputNums.length(); ++i) {
        char curr = inputNums.charAt(i);
        if (curr < prev) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "abc1deeef2hh hijk3lmno";
    System.out.println(input + ", " + isInOrder(input));
    input = "abc2deeef1hh hijk3lmno";
    System.out.println(input + ", " + isInOrder(input));
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc1deeef2hh hijk3lmno, true
abc2deeef1hh hijk3lmno, false
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

you can do with JS as well

```
function checkOrderedArrElm(array, order) {
    var m = 0;//Counter
    var current_num;
    var next_num;
    var result = array;
    var test;
    if (array !== undefined) {
        if (array.constructor === Array) { 
            result = true;
            while (m < array.length) {
                current_num = array[m];
                next_num = array[m + 1];
                if (typeof current_num === "number" &&
                        typeof next_num === "number") {
                    if (order) {
                        test = current_num >= next_num;
                    } else {
                        test = current_num <= next_num; 
                    }
                    if (test) {
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                m += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var strInput= "abc1deeef2hhh ijk3lmno";
function ExtractNumberFromString(strInput) {
    var indices = [];
    var inputVal = strInput;
    console.log(inputVal);
    for (var i = 0; i < inputVal.length; i++) {
      if (Number(inputVal[i])) indices.push(Number(inputVal[i]));
    }
    return indices; 
}
checkOrderedArrElm(ExtractNumberFromString(strInput), true));
```

You can check here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEYURSRVZMXH